# Prevent selecting multiple images and Select only single image in image upload function in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, sql-update

I want to stop selecting multiple Images and select only single image.
I working on a image upload in codeigniter in this example i can select multiple image but i have to select only single images threw it. so how can i change the selection to select single image.
 And also in this example when we edit uploaded images the old images will be get delete from database i want to change that but i don't know where and how to change the code for it .

this is my controller.

```
public function index()
{



    $getdata = $this->db->query("SELECT p.id,p.product_description,pd.product_name FROM g_product AS p INNER JOIN g_product_detail AS pd ON p.id = pd.product_id GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.id ASC");


    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('gallery2/index',array('data' => $getdata));



    $this->load->view('footer');


}

public function form()
{
    $this->load->view('gallery2/form', array('error' => ''));
}

public function delete($id)
{
    $getpic = $this->db->query("SELECT full_path FROM g_product_detail WHERE product_id = '{$id}'");
        foreach($getpic->result() as $row)
        {
            unlink($row->full_path);
        }
        $this->db->where('product_id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('g_product_detail');

        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('g_product');

        redirect('gallery2/index');
}

private function setup_upload_option()
{
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path']      = './uploadmulti';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'jpg|png|gif';
    $config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;
    $config['overwrite']        = False;
    return $config;
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $getrow = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM g_product WHERE id= '{$id}' ");
    $row = $getrow->row();


$getdetail = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM g_product_detail WHERE product_id = '{$id}'");

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('gallery2/edit',array('row' => $row,'result' => $getdetail));
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function do_update()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data = array(
                    'product_description' => $this->input->post('product_description')


                 );
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $te = $this->db->update('g_product',$data);

    if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'][0]))
    {
        $getpic = $this->db->query("SELECT full_path FROM g_product_detail WHERE product_id = '{$id}'");
        foreach($getpic->result() as $row)
        {
            unlink($row->full_path);
        }
        $this->db->where('product_id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('g_product_detail');

        $this->load->library('upload');
    $files = $_FILES;

        $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['userfile']['error'][$i];

        $this->upload->initialize($this->setup_upload_option());
        if($this->upload->do_upload() == False)
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('gallery2/form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $dataarray = array(

                'product_id' => $id,
                'product_name' =>$data['file_name'],
                'product_size' =>$data['file_size'],
                'product_ext' =>$data['file_ext'],
                'full_path' =>$data['full_path']
                );
            $this->db->insert('g_product_detail',$dataarray);


        }
    }
    redirect("gallery2/index");
    }
    else
    {
        redirect("gallery2/index");
    }


}


public function do_upload()
{
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $files = $_FILES;

$data = array(
'product_description' => $this->input->post('product_description')
            );
    $ch = $this->db->insert('g_product',$data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    if($ch > 0)
    {




    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['userfile']['error'][$i];

        $this->upload->initialize($this->setup_upload_option());
        if($this->upload->do_upload() == False)
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('gallery2/form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $dataarray = array(

                'product_id' => $id,
                'product_name' =>$data['file_name'],
                'product_size' =>$data['file_size'],
                'product_ext' =>$data['file_ext'],
                'full_path' =>$data['full_path']
                );
            $this->db->insert('g_product_detail',$dataarray);


        }
    }

    redirect('gallery2/index');
    }

}
```

Comment: for multiple issue need to change in your input type="file"

Comment: hello sir, what change i have to do???

Comment: There may be multiple or multiple="multiple" present in input type remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to stop selecting multiple Images and select only single image.

This seems to be in the view part of your file. 
If I am correct, the solution is changing `<input type="file" name="userfile" multiple>` to `<input type="file" name="userfile">`.
This should solve your multiple images selection problem.

In simple words, remove `multiple` attribute from your file input if it is used.

Comment: if the problem is solved, please accept the answer :-)

Comment: When i upload multiple & edit it and add new image the old images will be gone delete i have to change that when i edit images and upload a new image the old images will be not get delete.  can you help me over this...  ???

Comment: do_update() is this function you are using for updating the records? If yes, then the line unlink($row->full_path); is deleting the old images. Try removing that. Remove the foreach loop and the lines  $this->db->where('product_id',$id); &       $this->db->delete('g_product_detail');

Comment: yes sir it's working..  if you don't mind i have one more problem can i discuss,,,?

Comment: i have delete the images separately(one by one) ..   hear i can't delete single image. Pls can you help me over,,,,!!?

Comment: what problem you are facing in deleting single image? the code should work for deleting single image also.

Comment: yes sir ,,  after uploading multiple images when i want to delete some images from that uploaded image i can't delete single images i have to delete all the image. it's working for single image but in multiple image i can't delete image separately..

Comment: I guess you are uploading the images in g_product_detail table. So to delete single image, you have to consider the primary key of g_product_detail table and have to perform delete operation for that instead of using foreach loop.